# What is the equivalent to eth.pendingTransactions when running Parity?

Tags: web3js, parity, console

I'm running `parity --geth` and attaching to it with `geth attach`. I can use the web3.js that is built into that attached console. For example, I can get the latest block info.

However, when looking up how many transactions I have pending, I get this error:

```
> eth.pendingTransactions
Error: Method not found
    at web3.js:3104:20
    at web3.js:6191:15
    at get (web3.js:6091:38)
    at <unknown>
```

I understand that the underlying [parity RPC call](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-parity-module#parity_pendingtransactions) is different. I was hoping that the `--geth` flag on parity would take care of that. Is there any way to get the console to return this info?

Answer (score 1):

The `--geth` flag has no impact on the available APIs. Here are your options for pending transactions:

- [`parity_pendingTransactions`](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-parity-module#parity_pendingtransactions) returns a list of transactions currently in the queue.
- [`parity_pendingTransactionsStats`](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-parity-module#parity_pendingtransactionsstats) returns propagation stats for transactions in the queue.
- [`eth_newPendingTransactionFilter`](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-eth-module#eth_newpendingtransactionfilter) creates a filter in the node, to notify when new pending transactions arrive.

Comment: Right, I'm familiar with the RPC API, I was wondering if there was any way to do it from the web3.js object in `geth attach`. Are you implying that there is no way to do that, currently?

Comment: Well, Geth was designed to work with Geth in the first place, and Parity can not maintain a compatibility mode forever. In the long-term you can expect a Parity console at some point. Meanwhile, you can use the browser console or nodejs console, have a look at: https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Basic-Usage#javascript-console